# Search within Search Function in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I was going through the Search Function syntax and examples as per the following Office support document [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPLACE-REPLACEB-functions-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a).

Although the overall steps are clear as per the image attached here, one specific portion

```
 SEARCH("""",A2,SEARCH("""",A2)+1)
```

is not quite clear to me. Could someone explain how it leads to 10 in the results?

[image]

Comment: The second Search is determining the starting point for the original.  So basically, it's staying "Find a double-quote after the first double-quote".  The first double quote is at location 5, so starting at +1 (6) will give the location of the second double-quote which is at position 10.

Comment: @tigeravatar Thanks for your lucid explanation. Please answer it so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It leads to 10 because it is counting from the beginning as in the first search function. The only difference is that you are searching for the second ". The first " is the fifth character in the sentence, while the second is the tenth. You are still looking at the same cell, same characters.

If you want to start the count after the first " is located, you can look at the right part following the first quotation.

```
SEARCH("""",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-SEARCH("""",A2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It just finds the second occurrence of the double quotation mark. This is the simplest way to do such things, because SEARCH only finds the first occurrence and returns its position.

Answer (score 0):

SEARCH() finds the position of the requested character, in this case a quotation mark.  The embedded second SEARCH() gives the first search a new start position, which is after the first quotation mark at position 10.  Since it is starting at location 10 + 1, the next occurrence of a quotation mark is at position 24.